# Subtract property of a document in a collection to a property of another document in a different collection, and return the difference array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, pipeline

I have a Collection called A, where in there is a product array, 
and I have a collection B, which also has a product array, A & B relationship is one to many by _id, for each document in A , there may be multiple documents in B,also B's product array only consists of products from A's Product array.

This is collection A

```
    {
    "_id": "abcdefg",
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "1",
            "_product": "1",
            "quantity": 12
        },
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "_product": "2",
            "quantity": 32
        },
        {
            "_id": "3",
            "_product": "3",
            "quantity": 12
        }
    ]
}
```

These are two docs in B
Doc 1

```
{
"_id": "<<obj_id>>",
"A_id":"abcdefg",
"products": [
    {
        "_id": "<<_id>>",
        "_product": "1",
        "quantity": 6
    },
    {
        "_id": "<<_id>>",
        "_product": "2",
        "quantity": 16
    }
]
}
```

and DOC 2

```
{
"_id": "<<obj_id>>",
"A_id":"abcdefg",
"products": [
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "_product": "1",
        "quantity": 6
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "_product": "2",
        "quantity": 12
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "_product": "3",
        "quantity": 8
    }
]
}
```

Now, I need a pipeline/strategy in which I can get the difference of quantities of A's Products and (sum of all B'products) where ids of products are equal i.e something like this

```
[
  0,
  4,
  4
]
```

Comment: When you say "sum of all B'products", do you mean the total of B'products quantities?

Comment: Or do you mean a merge of doc 1 and 2 in collection B?

Comment: I mean sum the quantities in products array of B, Actually both will work..

Answer (score 0):

After 2 hours of grinding, finally got it to work somehow.

```
db.collectionb.aggregate([
{
  $unwind: "$products"
},
{
  $lookup:{
    from:"collectiona",
    localField:"A_id",
    foreignField:"_id",
    as:"colaref"
  }
},
{
 $unwind: "$colaref"
},
{
 $unwind:"$colaref.products"
},
{
 $project:{
  colaProducts:"$colaref.products",
  products:"$products",
  idEq:{ $eq:["$colaref,products._id","$products._id"]}
 }
},
{
 $match:{
  idEq: true
 }
},
{
 $project:{
  quantity:{
   $subtract:["$colaProducts.quantity","$products.quantity"]
  }
 }
}
])
```

if I add a match for the CollectionB document ID, then I get somewhat like I wanted.